# XQuery is Expected Error but XML already in SQL Table

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

Using 11.0 SP2 sql server manager.

I am trying to extract the values from the xml but I keep receiving the error 2205 "XQuery was expected". I do not understand why I am receiving that error since the XML is coming from a sql table. It is my understanding that the XQuery is needed to specify a path but if the data is already in the sql table referenced then why is a specific path needed?

```
Select 
XmlData.value('(/ItemInformation Culture/title)[1]','varchar(max)') as Title
From
[ArcDev].[dbo].[XmlRetrieval2]
```

> Msg 2205, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 XQuery
>   [ArcDev.dbo.XmlRetrieval2.XmlData.value()]: ")" was expected.

The table looks like this:
[XmlRetrieval2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXdny.jpg)

Comment: The specific error you posted is complaining about a missing ")", not about missing XQuery.  Is it the right error message?

Comment: That is the correct error message. I don't see where a ")" is missing though.

Comment: I suspect that it's complaining about the space between `ItemInformation` and `Culture`.  "Culture" isn't part of your tag name:  it's an attribute.  Try looking for `(/ItemInformation/title)[1]` and see if you get anywhere.

Comment: @Ann L. That worked. I removed the 'culture' and was able to extract the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You picture does not show the structure of your XML, if this does not solve your problem you should paste a (reduced) example of your XML.

From the picture I take that there is one element "ESRI_ItemInformation" with an attribute "Culture". It might be "ESRI" and "ItemInformation_Culture", but I don't think so...

If "title" is an element one level below the "ESRI_ItemInformation" your query might be this:

```
Select 
XmlData.value('(/ESRI_ItemInformation/title)[1]','varchar(max)') as Title
From
[ArcDev].[dbo].[XmlRetrieval2]
```

Comment: You and Ann L's answers worked. I was mistaking the 'Culture' as part of the tag name. Once I removed that I was able to successfully extract the data. Thanks for your help!